# What is the difference between a normal type and an atomic type?

Tags: c++

Let me just ask you a simple question about the atomic type in c++11.

**Is the atomic type affected by the "memory reorder" as much as the normal type?**

and if so,

**What is the difference between the normal type and the atomic type of relaxed memory?**

```
atomic<int> some_value = 1;
some_value.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

I wonder if it goes through the same process as the primitive int.
Does the atomic type of relaxed memory order mean that it does not occur to read and write atomically between the *memory* and the *cache*?

Comment: One question per question, please. And no questions that can be answered simply by reading your C++ book.

Comment: All right.Corrected the questions. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can skip the "please help" part as well, it's pretty obvious that you're seeking for help.

Comment: Thank you for your advice . Corrected the question.